# Can I call an object to another class?

Tags: java

I have two classes, as below:

```
public class JavaApplication12 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   NewClass aclass = new NewClass("rabbit", "bungalow");
   System.out.println(aclass.toString());
}}
```

and

```
public class NewClass {
String animal;
String building;

public NewClass(String A, String B){
animal=A;
building=B;}

NewClass class1 = new NewClass("cat", "house");
NewClass class2 = new NewClass("dog", "shed");

@Override
public String toString(){
    return animal+building;
}}
```

So I have an object called aclass in JavaApplication12 and I have been able to print out a toString of this. I want to be able to also print out a toString of the objects class1 and class2, which are in NewClass, but I want to print them in JavaApplication12, since this is the main class that I can run. If I were to just write

```
System.out.println(class1.toString());
```

in JavaApplication12, it obviously wouldn't know what to do as it can't see the object class1 in JavaApplication12. Is there any way to print out the toString of class1 in JavaApplication12?

EDIT

So I think I've figured out that I can't store the cat, dog, etc. information in the way I have - I think perhaps this is how I have managed to confuse some people so sorry about that!
Is there a way that I can store information like this in a second class and be able to call it to a main class i.e. say I want to be able to print `cat, dog` in JavaApplication1 but store this information in NewClass, and also store lots of other information of this sort. Would that be an ArrayList? Sorry again for confusion.

Comment: I don't understand your question, even after reading it twice.

Comment: Kudos to answers, such a difficult to understand ques

Comment: Make `class1` and `class2` public or add getters for accessing these from an other place.

Comment: @isawahatonce : Please umnark the question, its not javascript, its only java :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure about your question, but Ill try to answer : 
You have static variables and "normal" variables.
When you create an object of a class, you create each normal var for it, too. For example :

```
class Foo {
public int a; //For each obj
public static int b=3; //Global var of the class, acessable from anywhere
public Foo(int a) {
this.a=a;
}
}

System.out.println(new Foo(0).a); //-> 0
```

and of course there are static variables, and there not for each object, there in the class.

```
System.out.println(Foo.b); //-> 3
```

And so you can also have objs of the same class type in your class, example :

```
public Foo f;
```

**Solution 1 : As also some others did suggest, you can move them to your main method :**

```
public class JavaApplication12 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   NewClass aclass = new NewClass("rabbit", "bungalow");
   NewClass class1 = new NewClass("cat", "house");
   NewClass class2 = new NewClass("dog", "shed");
   System.out.println(aclass.toString());
}}
```

and

```
public class NewClass {
String animal;
String building;

public NewClass(String A, String B){
animal=A;
building=B;}


@Override
public String toString(){
    return animal+building;
}}
```

Accessing in main :

```
System.out.println(class1.toString());
```

**Solution 2 : Make them static, so you can acess them from your main method**

```
public class NewClass {
String animal;
String building;
public static NewClass class1 = new NewClass("cat", "house");
public static NewClass class2 = new NewClass("dog", "shed");

public NewClass(String A, String B){
animal=A;
building=B;}


@Override
public String toString(){
    return animal+building;
}}
```

then they are accessed in main:

```
System.out.println(NewClass.class1.toString());
```

Note that so you wont have the endless recursion G_H pointed out.

**Solution 3 : Have them for each obj(only if you need it so)**

```
public class NewClass {
String animal;
String building;
public NewClass class1 = new NewClass("cat", "house");
public NewClass class2 = new NewClass("dog", "shed");

public NewClass(String A, String B){
animal=A;
building=B;}


@Override
public String toString(){
    return animal+building;
}}
```

Note you have to access them from an obj, for example aclass :

```
System.out.println(aclass.class1.toString());
```

**That solution also provides more flexibility because you can then have different values there for different objs, for example, if each animal has two neighbors**

Answer (score 0):

Add `public` modifier before the `class1` and `class2` fields, or provide a [getter method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html). Then do this in your main class:

```
System.out.println(aclass.class1.toString());
System.out.println(aclass.class2.toString());
```

or if you provided getter methods:

```
System.out.println(aclass.getClass1().toString());
System.out.println(aclass.getClass2().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you created `class1` and `class2` as attributes of `NewClass` you have to move then to your main method. And then print it like you did with `aclass` like this:

```
public class JavaApplication12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       NewClass aclass = new NewClass("rabbit", "bungalow");
       System.out.println(aclass.toString());
       NewClass class1 = new NewClass("cat", "house");
       System.out.println(class1.toString());
       NewClass class2 = new NewClass("dog", "shed");
       System.out.println(class2.toString());
    }
}

public class NewClass {
    String animal;
    String building;

    public NewClass(String A, String B){
    animal=A;
    building=B;}

    // move these two lines to main
    //NewClass class1 = new NewClass("cat", "house");
    //NewClass class2 = new NewClass("dog", "shed");

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return animal+building;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating an object of type `NewClass` will invariably lead to a stackoverflow error in your case. Why? Because you've defined `class1` and `class2` as instance fields, which get immediately assigned. They are in turn instances of `NewClass`.

Which means that if you do this:

```
NewClass aclass = new NewClass("rabbit", "bungalow");
```

it also tries to create these two fields:

```
NewClass class1 = new NewClass("cat", "house");
NewClass class2 = new NewClass("dog", "shed");
```

which in turn will do the same. It is an endless recursion of creating new objects.

I suggest you first read up on what classes and instances are, how constructors work, field access and visibility and the difference between instance fields and static fields. Follow some Java tutorials to grasp the concepts of object orientation.